# Oracle - Help creating update statement (on hold)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need some help to converting a select statement to an update statement to update the `field_ind` value to Y. The primary key in `table_1` is on `field_id,create_date`. Here is the select statement used to find the records I need to update:

```
SELECT cd.field_id, cd.create_date, cd.field_ind FROM table_1 cd 
  JOIN table_2 ct
    ON cd.field_id = ct.field_id
   AND cd.field_ind = 'N'
  JOIN table_3 c
    ON c.field_id = cd.field_id
   AND c.field_rpt = 'N'
 WHERE cd.create_date IN (SELECT MAX(create_date) 
                            FROM table_1 
                           WHERE field_id = ct.field_id);
```

Sample data:

```
FIELD_ID CREATE_DATE FIELD_IND
     123 1/1/2016            N
     123 2/1/2017            N
     456 1/1/2016            N
     456 3/1/2017            N
     789 1/1/2015            N
     789 1/31/2017           N
```

Expected results:

```
FIELD_ID CREATE_DATE FIELD_IND
     123 1/1/2016            N
     123 2/1/2017            Y
     456 1/1/2016            N
     456 3/1/2017            Y
     789 1/1/2015            N
     789 1/31/2017           Y
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Update it where, and to what? Sample data and expected results might help clarify what you mean.

Comment: Update field_ind in table_1.

Comment: But to what? Your query gets that column - you want to update it to the same value it already has? Or you want to update all rows for an ID to have the same value as the value from the row with the most recent create date for that ID?

Comment: To Y, please see added sample data and expected results. The value would currently be N as in the filter (`AND cd.field_ind = 'N'`)

Comment: @AlexPoole Please see my updates. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are the other tables you're linking to relevant, or do you want to set the latest date to Y for all IDs regardless?

Answer (score 0):

You only need a minor variation of Ersin's approach to include the create date in the update:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET field_ind = 'Y'
WHERE (field_id, create_date, field_ind) IN (
  SELECT cd.field_id, cd.create_date, cd.field_ind FROM table_1 cd 
    JOIN table_2 ct
      ON cd.field_id = ct.field_id
     AND cd.field_ind = 'N'
    JOIN table_3 c
      ON c.field_id = cd.field_id
     AND c.field_rpt = 'N'
   WHERE cd.create_date IN (SELECT MAX(create_date) 
                              FROM table_1 
                             WHERE field_id = ct.field_id)
);

3 rows updated.

select * from table_1 order by field_id, create_date;

  FIELD_ID CREATE_DAT F
---------- ---------- -
       123 2016-01-01 N
       123 2017-02-01 Y
       456 2016-01-01 N
       456 2017-03-01 Y
       789 2016-01-01 N
       789 2017-01-31 Y
```

Basically you have to correlate the update with both the key fields if you only want the rows identified by your query to be updated. (That wasn't really clear from your earlier sample data/results; Ersin's answer worked for what you showed, but not for the situation you have now explained.) Including the `field_ind` isn't necessary, but as you have it in your original query I've included it in the `IN` clause - it could be removed from both though.

You could get rid of the subquery in your initial query, and hence slightly simplify the update too, with something like:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET field_ind = 'Y'
WHERE (field_id, create_date) IN (
  SELECT cd.field_id,
         max(cd.create_date) keep (dense_rank last order by create_date)
           as create_date
    FROM table_1 cd 
    JOIN table_2 ct
      ON cd.field_id = ct.field_id
     AND cd.field_ind = 'N'
    JOIN table_3 c
      ON c.field_id = cd.field_id
     AND c.field_rpt = 'N'
   GROUP BY cd.field_id
);
```

which updates the same three rows. I think that's equivalent here, based on the join conditions you've shown.